# Normalization on specific rows of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, normalization

I have a dataframe with many columns and rows. I want to do the following:

- Take all rows that DO NOT contain the text "phos" in the column "id"
- Normalize on these rows (e.g., median centering) on all intensity columns with the text "int_sam"
- Using the normalization factor/value as calculated above then subtract (data is log2 transformed) on each row that DO contain the
  text "phos" in the column "id", in a column-wise(sample-wise) manner.

Thank you very much in advance.
I do not have much experience in R and I am not a statistician either. So, an easy explanation possibly with the R code will be very helpful.
Thanks again.

```
int_sam_1 = c("2421432", "24242424", "NA", "4684757849", "NA", "10485040", "NA", 
          "6849400", "40300", "NA", "NA", "NA", "556456466", "4646456466", "246464266", "4564242646")
int_sam_2 = c("NA", "5342353", "14532556", "43566", "46367367", "768769769", "797899", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
          "686899", "7898979", "678568", "NA", "68886", "488")
int_sam_3 = c("11351", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1354151345", "1351351354", "314534", "1535", "3145354", "4353455", 
          "324535", "3543445", "34535", "34535534", "NA", "NA")
id = c("phos", "acet phos", "acet", "acet", "acet", "acet meth phos", "phos", "phos", "phos", "phos", "acet", 
   "meth", "meth phos", "phos", "meth phos", "phos")
df = cbind.data.frame(int_sam_1, int_sam_2, int_sam_3, id)
```

Comment: Do you want to normalize each column with respect to itself?

Comment: Thanks. Yes. For the rows that do not contain "phos" it can be global, meaning that means/medians of all the samples are centered.

Answer (score 0):

try following

your data

```
int_sam_1 = c(2421432, 24242424, NA, 4684757849, NA, 10485040, NA, 
              6849400, 40300, NA, NA, NA, 556456466, 4646456466, 246464266, 4564242646)
int_sam_2 = c(NA, 5342353, 14532556, 43566, 46367367, 768769769, 797899, NA, NA, NA, 
              686899, 7898979, 678568, NA, 68886, 488)
int_sam_3 = c(11351, NA, NA, NA, 1354151345, 1351351354, 314534, 1535, 3145354, 4353455, 
              324535, 3543445, 34535, 34535534, NA, NA)
id = c("phos", "acet phos", "acet", "acet", "acet", "acet meth phos", "phos", "phos", "phos", "phos", "acet", 
       "meth", "meth phos", "phos", "meth phos", "phos")
df = cbind.data.frame(int_sam_1, int_sam_2, int_sam_3, id)
```

subsetting to columns without phos and calculating the global median

```
df.sub <- df %>% filter(!grepl("phos",id))
df.median <- median(as.vector(as.matrix(df.sub[,1:3])),na.rm = T)
```

substracting golbal median from each value in column 1-3  where you have phos

```
df <- df %>% 
mutate(int_sam_1=ifelse(grepl('phos',id),int_sam_1-df.median, int_sam_1)) %>% 
mutate(int_sam_2=ifelse(grepl('phos',id),int_sam_2-df.median, int_sam_2)) %>%
mutate(int_sam_3=ifelse(grepl('phos',id),int_sam_3-df.median, int_sam_3))
```

Comment: sorry just saw that you want the everything for the columns without phos. Edited accordingly  `filter(grepl("phos",id))` to `filter(!grepl("phos",id))`